# Bundling Failed Error after Upgrading React Native

Tags: react-native, npm

In researching how to mock `AsyncStorage` for testing, I discovered that I should be using the `react-community` version instead of importing it from `react-native` (although importing it from `react-native` seemed to be working fine with no warnings or anything).

`yarn add @react-native-community/async-storage` was fine but `react-native link @react-native-community/async-storage` wasn't working so I followed an answer somewhere and ran `react-native-git-upgrade` and then I was able to link.

But, now my app won't run:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native/Libraries/Components/View/ViewStylePropTypes` from `/Users/TuzMacbookPro2017/Development/QMG-local/APPS/ELECTRO/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/src/createAnimatedComponent.js`: Module `react-native/Libraries/Components/View/ViewStylePropTypes` does not exist in the Haste module map
This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
```

I see around the internet that `PropTypes` (which I never use myself) is being used in some dependencies but has been deprecated or moved or something. Granted, it didn't give any problems before.

Here's various things I've tried to fix it and nothing has helped:

1. `npm update`
2. `npm audit fix` - says react and react-native missing, so:
3. `npm i`
4. `npm audit fix` - runs
5. (Try app: Same proptypes error on run)
6. `sudo npm cache verify`
7. (Try app: Same error)
8. `rm -rf node_modules && yarn install && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react* && npm start --reset-cache`
9. (Try app: Same error)

If it's of any use, here's my `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "Electro",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.3.4",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "^0.59.6",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-global-font": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-render-html": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-uuid": "^1.4.9",
    "react-navigation": "^3.9.1",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-test-utils": "^0.3.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sugar": "^2.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.12.1",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest-expo": "^32.0.0",
    "jsdom": "^14.1.0",
    "mock-async-storage": "^2.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3"
  },
  "private": true,
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts"
    ]
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to get my app running again??? (even restoring the last commit doesn't work! I'll try downgrading react native...)

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I was able to get my app to run again by restoring my commit, and then changing the `react-native` version is `package.json` back to `0.57`